# Error para conseguir la contraseña en una base de datos en mongodb con mongoose para autenticar usuaio

Tags: nodejs

Hola estoy haciendo una pagina web y estoy desarrollando la parte de autenticacion. Todo va bien hasta la hora de hacer las pruebas y ver si al ingresar el email lo encuentra y lo autentica, lo hace pero a la hora de comparar la contraseña me salta este error: (node:4635) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: User.matchPassword is not a function
uso la libreria passport y este es el codigo

```
passport.use(new local_stategy({
    usernameField: 'email'
}, async (email, password, done) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({email: email});
    if (!user){
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Not User Found.'});
    } else {
        const match = await User.matchPassword(password);
        console.log(match);
        if (match) {
            return done(null, user);
        } else {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect Password.'});
        }
    }
}));
```

y este es el codigo de User:

```
UserSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function (password){
    return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listo ya pude solucionarlo, cambiando matchPassword por comparePassword y me funciono, y tambien usando user en ves de User

Comment: Por favor, considera ser más específico en cuanto a tu respuesta. La respuesta le puede servir a futuros usuarios. Este tipo de respuestas se considera de baja calidad.